# Can not create a directory on Mount usb drive

Tags: usb, permissions, mount

I want to create a cronjob that makes a backup on a usb drive. The script works well but if the machine is restarted, the usb drive is unmounted. So I connect via ssh and run the following command to mount the usb drive:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/backups/
```

and as you can see the usb drive is mounted

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           776M  4,7M  772M   1% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2   29G   11G   18G  38% /
tmpfs           3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4,0M     0  4,0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M  121M  132M  48% /boot/firmware
tmpfs           776M   88K  776M   1% /run/user/126
tmpfs           776M   80K  776M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1        58G  3,8M   58G   1% /mnt/backups
```

but when the cronjob run or I manually exec the bash I get the following error:

```
2021-12-24T07:37:12.790+0100    Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating metadata file 24122021-2/website/users.metadata.json: open 24122021-2/website/users.metadata.json: permission denied
```

I run the following command to change permission, but same problem:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /mnt/backups/
```

Comment: Ubuntu Server, desktop version? USB drive file system?(in the terminal:lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID or lsblk -f). You should define an access control list for the folder: for example, we change the owner to your username: sudo chown $USER /mnt/backups/. Editing fstab to automount partitions at startup. Creating a cronjob from the same user.

Comment: Unmount it and check permissions to `/mnt` and `/mnt/backups` folders.